MAUI - How can slider reduction be prevented?
In my MAUI application, I am using a slider to set a timer. The user can set the desired time by sliding the slider to the appropriate position. Once the timer is started, I want to prevent the user from reducing the set time until the timer completes its countdown. This ensures that the timer runs uninterrupted for the full duration initially set by the user. How can I do this on my MAUI application?
The user should be able to increase the timer using the slider. Restriction is only to reduce the timer.
Below is the Slider code added on the XAML page:
<Slider
    x:Name="watchme_slider"
    Grid.Column="1"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    MinimumTrackColor="#1c98d7"
    MaximumTrackColor="#9a9a9a"
    ThumbImageSource="ic_thumb_xx.png"
    ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged"
    Maximum="0.166666667"
    Minimum="0"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>


You can try to set the InputTransparent Property as false when the timer run.

Very interesting max value.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I tried setting the InputTransparent property to false when the timer started; there was no change at that time. So, I set the InputTransparent property to true when the timer started; at that time, I could not reduce the time, and I was also not able to increase it. In my application, I want the user to increase the time, but they should not be able to reduce it.

You can create a property (e.g. public bool InputTransparent) for the view model of your current page and implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged for it. Then you can bind it to the property InputTransparent of Slider.
I achieved the functionality on my side, you can refer to the following code:
1.create a view model(MyViewModel.cs)
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _inputTransparent;
    public bool InputTransparent
    {
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _inputTransparent, value);
        }
        get { return _inputTransparent; }
    }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

2.On the MainPage.xaml.cs, I added a Button to start a Timer and a Label to display the value of Slider.
MainPage.xaml
    <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">

        <Slider
         x:Name="slider"
         BackgroundColor="White"
         MinimumTrackColor="#1c98d7"
         MaximumTrackColor="#9a9a9a"
         ValueChanged="watchme_slider_ValueChanged"
                 
         Maximum="360"
         Minimum="0"
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               
         InputTransparent="{Binding InputTransparent}"            
                />
        <Label x:Name="displayLabel"
               Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},
                              Path=Value,
                              StringFormat='The Slider value is {0:F0}'}"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />


        <Button
                x:Name="StartTimerBtn"
                Text="Start Timer"
                Clicked="OnTimerClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />


    </VerticalStackLayout>

MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MyViewModel myViewModel { get; set; }
    
    //Indicates whether the value of the slider is increasing or decreasing
    bool IsIncrease = false;

    //Indicates whether the timer starts or ends
    bool IsTimerStart = false;


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myViewModel= new MyViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = myViewModel;

    }

    private void OnTimerClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IsTimerStart = true;

        IDispatcherTimer timer;

        timer = Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {

            myViewModel.InputTransparent = false;

            IsTimerStart = false;
        };
        timer.Start();

        //time is over


    }

    private void watchme_slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Slider slider = (Slider)sender;
        double value = slider.Value;

        IsIncrease = e.NewValue > e.OldValue;  
       
        if (IsTimerStart)
        {

            if (!IsIncrease)
            {
                myViewModel.InputTransparent = true;

                slider.Value = e.OldValue;
            }
        }

        myViewModel.InputTransparent = false;
    }
}

Note:
1.On the event of watchme_slider_ValueChanged of Slider, I used the parameter e.NewValue and e.OldValue from ValueChangedEventArgs e to determine if the Slider is triggering an increase or a decrease event. If the reduction event is triggered, set the value of myViewModel.InputTransparent to true, and set the value of the Slider to the previous value(slider.Value = e.OldValue;), and vice versa.
2.In fact, you can also try to use property IsEnabled to achieve this.

This is working as expected but I have a problem with this implementation, I have updated the question with that details. Could you please check that?

Thanks for your feedback. One problem, one thread. For the new problem, you can create a new thread, we are all willing to help you.  :)

I have created a new thread for the new issue, could you please check that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78705451/maui-how-to-disable-the-dragcompletedcommand-of-slider-when-click-lower-time

A colleague of mine is working on this for you.  :)

I found a new issue with the implementation of this, could you please help me. Posted a new question with that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79053890/maui-slider-thumbimagesource-is-not-moving-after-disabling-the-slider-to-select
