MAUI: How to disable the DragCompletedCommand of Slider when click lower time
Using this thread I implemented the slider reduction prevention logic on my MAUI application.
But I have a DragCompletedCommand also in the Slider and which will do some actions. Here when clicking the lower time on slider at that time also the DragCompletedCommand was hitting and doing those actions. How can I disable that?
I tried like below: Added a bool variable on viewmodel and check it's value before doing the actions.
public ICommand DragCompletedCommand => new Command(OnDragCompleted);

private void OnDragCompleted(object obj)
{
    if (invokeDragCompleted)
    {
        //My actions
    }
}

I am setting that bool value from homepage.xaml.cs page's ValueChanged event.
public void SliderValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        Slider slider = (Slider)sender;
        IsIncrease = args.NewValue > args.OldValue;
        if (!IsIncrease)
        {
            hpvm.InputTransparent = true;
            slider.Value = args.OldValue;
            value = args.OldValue;
            hpvm.invokeDragCompleted = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hpvm.InputTransparent = false;
            slider.Value = args.NewValue;
            value = args.NewValue;
            hpvm.invokeDragCompleted = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>" + ex);
    }
}

But this event is always firing when the timer runs and hitting if and else block alternatively. So the bool value is getting true from here and doing the actions on the Viewmodel. Is there any way to set the bool value to false when choosing a lower time?
My Slider code:
<Slider 
    x:Name="watchme_slider"
    Grid.Column="1"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    MinimumTrackColor="#1c98d7"
    MaximumTrackColor="#9a9a9a"
    ThumbImageSource="ic_thumb_xx.png"
    ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged"
    InputTransparent="{Binding InputTransparent}"
    Maximum="0.166666667"
    Minimum="0"
    DragCompletedCommand="{Binding DragCompletedCommand}"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

The timer is running in every second that hits the ValueChanged event. If the user touch or drag the Slider, at that time also ValueChanged event is firing. Is there any way to find which type of event is triggered?
Update
Updated the slider code like below:
<Slider 
    x:Name="watchme_slider"
    Grid.Column="1"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    MinimumTrackColor="#1c98d7"
    MaximumTrackColor="#9a9a9a"
    ThumbImageSource="ic_thumb_xx.png"
    ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged"
    InputTransparent="{Binding InputTransparent}"
    Maximum="0.166666667"
    Minimum="0"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Slider.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="DragCompleted"
            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=BindingContext.DragCompletedCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference watchme_slider}}"/>
    </Slider.Behaviors>
</Slider>

Updated HomePageViewModel class with partial keyword:
public partial class HomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged

Commented below ICommand:
//public ICommand DragCompletedCommand => new Command(OnDragCompleted);

Added RelayCommand and rename the function to DragCompleted:
[RelayCommand]
public void DragCompleted(object obj)
{
    var slider = obj as Slider;
    Debug.WriteLine("slider.Value:>>" + slider.Value);
    Debug.WriteLine("preValue:>>" + preValue);
    if (slider.Value > preValue)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("do some work");
        preValue = slider.Value;
    }
}


May I ask what .NET version and platform do you use?

@LiqunShen-MSFT .net 8 on android and ios platforms

You set the slider.Value = args.OldValue; in SliderValueChanged event. That's the reason why both if and else block are hitted.
From my understanding, you want to do some actions in DragCompletedCommand only when the slider increase its value. Right?
I may add a new field maybe call it preValue in ViewModel to store the previous value of slider.
private double preValue;

And check if the current value is larger,
    [RelayCommand]
    public void DragCompleted(object obj)
    {
        var slider = obj as Slider;
        if (slider.Value > preValue)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("do some work");
            preValue = slider.Value;
        }
    }

Here is the XAML, I use EventToCommandBehavior from Maui CommunityToolkit.
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         ...
         Title="HomePage"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Name="page">

    <Slider 
        x:Name="watchme_slider"
        Grid.Column="1"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        MinimumTrackColor="#1c98d7"
        MaximumTrackColor="#9a9a9a"
        ThumbImageSource="ic_thumb_xx.png"
        ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged"
        InputTransparent="{Binding InputTransparent}"
        Maximum="0.166666667"
        Minimum="0"     
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Slider.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="DragCompleted"
            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference page}, Path=BindingContext.DragCompletedCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference watchme_slider}}"
                />
        </Slider.Behaviors>
    </Slider>


I tried this, but the DragCompleted event is not firing for the initial time.

Do you mean DragCompleted event not fire?  Could you please share the relevant code about DragCompleted ?

I use RelayCommand and EventToCommandBehavior for Slider. Do you use the same code as mine?

RelayCommand was missing on my code, let me try again

Still not firing, I have updated the question with the recent changes I made, could you please check.

Do you set the x:Name="page" for the ContentPage?

I have a cancel option also on the UI, when I tap the cancel the tap option I set the slider value to 0 like this: watchme_slider.Value = 0;. But after this implementation it is not moving to 0, I mean the slider is not resetting.

Could you please post the relevant code about the cancel option? And from my understanding, what you want is preventing the slider to reduce the value. Is that the reason which cause the resetting not work?

When cancel just resetting the slider time to 0 and for that I am using this one line code: watchme_slider.Value = 0;. Preventing the slider to reduce the value - this was the new requirement and that is working now. After its implementation the resetting was not working.

In SliderValueChanged event, seems when args.NewValue > args.OldValue;, it will set slider.Value = args.OldValue;. Then I think that's why it cannot reset the slider value to 0.

Thanks for the reason, I have fixed it with one bool variable and Task.Delay.

I found a new issue with the implementation of this, could you please help me. Posted a new question with that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79053890/maui-slider-thumbimagesource-is-not-moving-after-disabling-the-slider-to-select
